# RabbitMQ multi-threaded channels and queue binding

Tags: java, multithreading, rabbitmq, amqp

I have inherited some legacy RabbitMQ code that is giving me some serious headaches.  Can anyone help, ideally pointing to some *"official" documentation* where I can browse for similar questions?

We create some channels receive responses from workers which perform a search using channels like so:

```
channelIn.queueDeclare("", false, false, true, null);
channelIn.queueBind("", AmqpClient.NAME_EXCHANGE,
     AmqpClient.ROUTING_KEY_ROOT_INCOMING + uniqueId);
```

My understanding from browsing mailing lists and forums is that

- declaring a queue with an empty name allows the server auto-generate a unique name, and
- queues must have a globally unique name.

Is this true?

Also, in the second line above, my understanding based on some liberal interpretation of blogs and mailing lists is that queuebind with an empty queue name automatically binds to the last created queue. It seems nice because then you wouldn't have to pull the auto-generated name out of the clunky DeclareOK object.

Is this true?  If so, will this work in a multithreaded environment?

I.e. is it possible some channel will bind itself to another channel's queue, then if that other channel closes, the incorrectly bound channel would get an error trying to use the queue? (note that the queue was created with autodelete=true.)  My testing leads me to think yes, but I'm not confident that's where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot be certain that this will work in a multithreaded environment.  It may be fine a high percentage of the time but it is possible you will get the wrong queue.  Why take the risk?
Wouldn't this be better and safer?

```
String queueName = channelIn.queueDeclare("", false, false, true, null).getQueue();
channelIn.queueBind(queueName, AmqpClient.NAME_EXCHANGE,
 AmqpClient.ROUTING_KEY_ROOT_INCOMING + uniqueId);
```

Not exactly clunky.

Comment: You're correct. That's not bad at all. Thought I had to do some lookup with the return object. Would be nice to know what the expected behavior is though as there are other similar fuzzy lines in my codebase.

Comment: If there are similar fuzzy lines I would prioritize looking for ways, like this, to remove the fuzziness.  It maybe that the original code was written for an earlier version of the API and there are now better ways to handle these kind of situations. On the whole, if used correctly, the rabbitMQ client should thread safe.

Comment: Was really hoping to find a pointer to some documentation (i.e. not just StackOverflow posts and the RabbitMQ list) on how errors are handled, what happens when connections are closed, what happens if you try to open a channel twice... that sort of thing.  I guess I will continue to migrate things piece by piece via trial and error.

Answer (score 0):

**Q: What happens when a queue is declared with no name?**

**A: The server picks a unique name for the queue.** When no name is supplied, the RabbitMQ server will generate a unique-for-that-RabbitMQ-cluster name, create a queue with that name, and then transmit the name back to the client that called `queue.declare`. RabbitMQ does this in a thread-safe way internally (e.g. many clients calling `queue.declare` with blank names will never get the same name). [Here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-reference.html#domain.queue-name) is the documentation on this behavior.

**Q: Do queue names need to be globally unique?**

**A: No, but they may need to be in your use case.** Any number of publishers and subscribers can share a queue. Queue declarations are idempotent, so if 2 clients declare a queue with the same name and settings at the same time, or at different times, the server state will be the same as if just one declared it. Queues with blank names, however, will never collide. Consider declaring a queue with a blank name as if it were two operations: an RPC asking RabbitMQ "give me a globally unique name that you will reserve just for my use", and then idempotently declaring a queue with that name.

**Q: Will `queue.bind` with a blank name bind to the last created queue in a multithreaded environment?**

**A: Yes, but you should not do that; it achieves nothing, is confusing, and has unspecified/poorly-specified behavior.** This technique is largely pointless and prone to bugs in client code (What if lines got added between the declare and the add? Then it would be very hard to determine what queue was being bound).

Instead, use the return value of `queueDeclare`; that return value will contain the name of the queue that was declared. **If you declared a queue with no name, the return value of `queueDeclare` will contain the new globally-unique name provided by RabbitMQ.** You can provide that explicitly to subsequent calls that work with that queue (like binding it).

For an additional reason not to do this, the [documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-reference.html#queue.bind.queue) regarding blank-queue-name behavior is highly ambiguous:

> The client MUST either specify a queue name or have previously
>   declared a queue on the same channel

What does that mean? If more than one queue was declared, which one will be bound? What if the previously-declared queue was then deleted on that same channel? This seems like a very good reason to be as explicit as possible and not rely on this behavior.

**Q: Can queues get deleted "underneath" channels connected to them?**

**A: Yes, in specific circumstances.** Minor clarification on your question's terminology: channels don't "bind" themselves to queues: a channel can consume a queue, though. Think of a channel like a network port and a queue like a remote peer: you don't bind a port to a remote peer, but you can talk to more than one peer through the same port. Consumers are the equivalent of connected sockets; not channels. Anyway:

Channels don't matter here, but consumers and connections do (can have more than one consumer, even to the same queue, per channel; you can have more than one channel per connection). Here are the situations in which a queue can be deleted "underneath" a channel subscribing to it (I may have missed some, but these are all the non-disastrous--e.g. "the server exploded" conditions I know of):

1. A queue was declared with `exclusive` set to true, and the *connection* on which the queue was declared closes. The channel used to declare the queue can be closed, but so long as the connection stays open the queue will keep existing. Clients connected to the exclusive queue will see it disappear. However, clients may not be able to access the exclusive queue for consumption in the first place if it is "locked" to its declarer--[the documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-reference.html#queue.declare.exclusive) is not clear on what "used" means with regards to exclusive locking.
2. A queue which is manually deleted via a `queue.delete` call. In this case, all consumers connected to the queue may encounter an error the next time they try to use it.

**Note** that in many client situations, consumers are often "passive"
    enough that they won't realize that a queue is gone; they'll just
    listen forever on what is effectively a closed socket. Publishing to
    a queue, or attempting to redeclare it with `passive` (existence
    poll) is guaranteed to surface the nonexistence; consumption alone
    is not: sometimes you will see a "this queue was deleted!" error,
    sometimes it will take minutes or hours to arrive, sometimes you
    will never see such an error if all you're doing is consuming.

**Q: Will `auto_delete` queues get deleted "underneath" one consumer when another consumer exits?**

**A: No.** `auto_delete` queues are deleted sometime after the *last* consumer leaves the queue. So if you start two consumers on an auto_delete queue, you can exit one without disturbing the other. [Here's](https://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-reference.html#queue.declare.auto-delete) the documentation on that behavior.

Additionally, queues which expire (via [per-queue TTL](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ttl.html)) follow the same behavior: the queue will only go away sometime after the last consumer leaves.